# Using OpenFileDialog with windows form not opening

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am making a GUI with a windows form and OpenFileDialog is not opening on button click.

I am using the following code and nothing happens when I click on my button designated as button1.

```
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        Stream^ myStream;
        OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

        openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
            {
                String^ strfilename = openFileDialog1->FileName;
                String^ Readfile = File::ReadAllText(strfilename);
                MessageBox::Show(Readfile); // This is a test line


                //myStream->Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually assign the button's Click event handler?  It isn't unusual for a programmer's machine to have bad shell extensions that can make this dialog fail.  Try both the x86 and x64 builds to verify.  If one works but not the other then you'll have to get the machine fixed with SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.

Comment: IIRC, `openFileDialog1->ShowDialog()` always throws an RPC exception (I don't remember which one). See that your code doesn't break out.

Comment: I didn't actually assign the button's Click event handler. However, I deleted the button and created a new one using the exact same code and it worked. Still not sure what the original problem was but thank you for the help.